# how to add a conditional legend to a bar chart? "plt.bar"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

how can I add a legend to this bar chart for each color?

```
colors = [{i<0: 'blue', 0<=i<=3.25: 'green', i>3.25: 'red'}[True] for i in decades_inflation['inflation_decade_avg']]
plt.figure(figsize=(18,9))
plt.bar(decades_inflation['decade'], decades_inflation['inflation_decade_avg'], color=colors, width=0.9)
plt.title('Inflation_rate_per_decade', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

I have tried adding this line:

```
legends = [{j<0: 'below zero', 0<=j<=3.25: 'between 0 and avg', j>3.25: 'above avg'}[True] for j in decades_inflation['inflation_decade_avg']]
plt.legend(legends)
```

but this only showed the first color

many thanks in advance, I have researched this for a while but I couldn't find yet what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of the legend lines you have there, use these lines... Tried with some dummy data. Hope this is what you are looking for

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
custom_lines = [Line2D([0], [0], color='b', lw=4),
                Line2D([0], [0], color='g', lw=4),
                Line2D([0], [0], color='r', lw=4)]
plt.legend(custom_lines, ['below zero', 'between 0 and avg', 'above avg'])
```

**Plot**

[image]